# Vue can not read property 'extend' of undefined from library

Tags: vue.js, extend, lib

When I dynamicaly load component from library file then i have en error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
    at Module.fb15 (index.ts:21)
    at n (bootstrap:19)
    at 0273 (bootstrap:83)
    at cmp.umd.min.js:1
    at universalModuleDefinition:9
    at universalModuleDefinition:1
fb15 @ index.ts:21
n @ bootstrap:19
0273 @ bootstrap:83
(anonymous) @ cmp.umd.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ universalModuleDefinition:9
(anonymous) @ universalModuleDefinition:1
```

[image: problematic generated code]

I load component in this way:

```
//this is sfc from main app source code 
<template>
  <component :is="gwComponent" />
</template>

<script>
import externalComponent from "@/utils/external-component";
export default {
  name: "extensions-view",
  components: {},
  props: ["_type_", "_instance_"],
  data() {
    return {
      info: {
        description: ""
      },
      instances: []
    };
  },
  computed: {
    gwComponent() {
      if (this._instance_ == "all") {
        return () => import("../components/ExtensionsInstances.vue");
      } else {
        return () =>
          externalComponent(
              window.location.origin +
              "/assets/gw/" +
              this._type_ +
              "/cmp.umd.min.js"
          );
      }
    }
  },

};
</script>
```

```
// src/utils/external-component.js from main app source code
export default async function externalComponent(url) {
  const name = url
    .split("/")
    .reverse()[0]
    .match(/^(.*?)\.umd/)[1];

  if (window[name]) return window[name];

  window[name] = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.async = true;
    script.addEventListener("load", () => {
      resolve(window[name]);
    });
    script.addEventListener("error", () => {
      reject(new Error(`Error loading ${url}`));
    });
    script.src = url;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  });

  return window[name];
}
```

The file `cmp.umd.min.js` is created by compiling another SFC with
`npx vue-cli-service build --target lib --formats umd-min --no-clean --dest build/bin --name 'cmp' src/components/ExtEntryPointComponent.vue`.

This compiled file is created and placed in the right place by user. Finaly user can add some extensions to the main app, without main app source code.

## @edit

in dev mode i have some more informations but this still told me nothing :/
[image]

my code based at this article:
https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/

Comment: really nobody can help ??

Comment: Do you found a solution?

Comment: Not for SFC. This concept is possible only with `Vue.component{"cmp", {
  template: '<li>This is a todo</li>'
})` syntax ...

Comment: Explicitly setting `"module": "ESNext"` in my  `tsconfig.json` helped when running into the same error using Jest.

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting it as a function that returns `Vue.extend()`

```
export default () => Vue.extend({
   ...
})
```

Then when you import it, call that function.

Comment: Do you mean the function `externalComponent(url)`? I will try..

Answer (score 0):

remove your vuetify script tag on your master index.html and the error will go away